# Animate path loaded from external svg

Tags: animation, svg

When I define a simple path with an animation in a svg and use it immediately, everything works fine (see the following snippet)

```html
<html>

<body>
  <svg width='100%' height='100%' preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax">
    <defs>
      <symbol id="myloader" width="100%" height="100%" x="0px" y="0px" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 50 80">       
        <path fill="#000" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="xml" dur="0.6s" from="0 25 25" repeatCount="indefinite" to="360 25 25" type="rotate"/>
        </path>
      </symbol>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#myloader"></use>
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Now when I try to move this svg to an external file and load it from there, the svg is shown but the animation doesn't run.

loaders.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" x="0px" y="0px" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 50 80">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="myloader" width="100%" height="100%" x="0px" y="0px" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" viewBox="0 0 50 80">
            <path fill="#000" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="xml" dur="0.6s" from="0 25 25" repeatCount="indefinite" to="360 25 25" type="rotate"/>
            </path>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

html

```
<html>

<body>
  <svg width='100%' height='100%' preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax">
    <use xlink:href="loaders.svg#myloader"></use>
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Is this expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong. I want the animation to run from the external resource too.

Comment: Works fine for me on Firefox 57 on a Mac.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for testing this out, I downloaded Firefox and it does indeed work there. But not in Chrome nor Safari (on macOS), no idea who's right or wrong here.

Comment: Firefox is right. I guess Chrome/Safari simply haven't implemented this.